# AVCaptureScreen on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, avfoundation, screen-capture

I have been trying to use the AVCaptureScreenInput class on Mountain Lion 10.8:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureScreenInput_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I downloaded the following sample code provided by Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

But when I ran it, it did not capture my screen. Instead it just showed a green screen where my screen was supposed to be.

Someone else noticed the problem here: http://openradar.appspot.com/12220970

Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

Comment: I hate that the sample code results in "...due to error (null)" on the console output after a successful recording. Misleading, because there is no error in this case. Just a completely unrelated OpenCL bug, apparently.

Answer (score 4):

Doing the following "fixed" the problem. I don't know why:

`defaults write com.apple.cmio CMIO_Unit_Input_ASC.DoNotUseOpenCL -bool YES`

I filed a bug here: https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/41/wo/Dtr5y1Zj8ikA0Rjw6xYON0/6.83.28.0.9

Bug ID = 13917881

Comment: it appears that this issue has been resolved in the latest software update for Mac OS X 10.8. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

> "High" session preset doesn't work in Mac OS 10.8. But on changing to
>   other preset like medium or any other resolution sample code will work.